# Populating a ComboBox with a Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, combobox

My Array is a list of Pokemon Names read from a text file and then stored into an Array in the PokemonData class seen below

```
        private string[] pokemonNames;
        private StreamReader readNames;

        public PokemonData()
        {
            readNames = new StreamReader(setDirectory() + @".\PokemonNames.txt");
            pokemonNames = new string[256];
            populateArray(pokemonNames, readNames);

        }

        public string[] populateArray(string[] pokemonNames, StreamReader readNames)
        {
            string pokemonName = readNames.ReadLine();
            int i = 0;
            while (pokemonName != null)
            {
                pokemonNames[i] = pokemonName.Trim();
                pokemonName = readNames.ReadLine();
                i++;
            }
            readNames.Close();
            return pokemonNames;
        }

        public string[] getPokemonNames()
        {
            return pokemonNames;
        }
```

What I want to do is now populate an Combobox using WPF with all the names inside the array. I have tried googling this and frequently alot of the answers have classes setup much like this:

```
Class ExampleClass {
    Public ExampleClass() {
         string PokemonName; {get; set;}
     }
}
```

I believe there is an assignment going on here, but I am unsure. C# isn't my usual language and this is my first time creating a gui. Could someone please guide me through so I could finish this.

I have tried doing a handful of things such as the code below and Databinding. At this point I believe I am missing something.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StarterEdit"
        xmlns:Collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=System.Runtime.Extensions" x:Class="StarterEdit.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Starter Edit" Height="420" Width="550">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,11" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="530">
        <Label Content="Squirtle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Starter One"/>
        <Label Content="Bulbasaur" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Starter Two"/>
        <Label Content="Charmander" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="445,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Starter Three"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="NameList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedIndex="0" Cursor="Arrow" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" ToolTip="List of Pokemon names">

        </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

Here is my MainWindow class

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> pokemonNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        PokemonData pokemonData = new PokemonData();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NameList.ItemsSource = pokemonData.getPokemonNames(); //method that returns string array 
            NameList.ItemsSource = pokemonNames; //this is a dictionary
        }

    }
```

What I'm trying to do is using WPF I want to populate my comboBox with the data from the PokemonData Class, specifically the array containing all the names. The problem is whenever I bind the data or set the data it never displays on the gui or in the comboBox.

Comment: Is this wpf // winforms // asp?

Comment: You don't state what issue you're having.  You also haven't shown what `getPokemonNames()` is (is it really `populateArray()`?), and your comment says `pokemonNames` is a dictionary when your earlier code shows it's an array.  `setDirectory() + @".\PokemonNames.txt"` will be problematic, though, because you're appending a `.` to whatever `setDirectory()` returns.  It should be just `setDirectory() + @"\PokemonNames.txt"` or, better yet, `Path.Combine(setDirectory(), "PokemonNames.txt")`.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia wpf

Comment: But what is the problem?  The names aren't being loaded into the `ComboBox`?  The two lines that set `NameList.ItemsSource`, where are they located and what's triggering them?  Where is this `PokemonData` class being used?  You may need to show the relevant XAML and code-behind of the `Window` containing the `ComboBox`.

Comment: @BACON The combo box wont display the data that I give it is the whole problem here. I've updated my post to show the other relevant code.

Comment: You are assigning `NameList.ItemsSource` twice, the latter being to an empty `Dictionary<>`.  Remove that second assignment and see how that looks.

Comment: @BACON I can't believe it was that, I spent far too long trying to work it out thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If shortly, the next code must work correctly, just do this initialization after loading data from the file.

```
NameList.ItemsSource = pokemonData.getPokemonNames();
```

If you want a better solution, you can find it below (when Pokemons collection have changed UI would be updated automatically):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PokemonData(setDirectory() + @".\PokemonNames.txt");
    }
}

public class Pokemon
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PokemonData
{
    public ObservableCollection<Pokemon> Pokemons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Pokemon>();

    public PokemonData(string path)
    {
        LoadData(path);
    }

    private void LoadData(string path)
    {
        Pokemons.Clear();
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                string pokemonName = stream.ReadLine();

                if (pokemonName != null)
                    Pokemons.Add(new Pokemon { ID = i, Name = pokemonName.Trim() });
                else break;

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Pokemons}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```